# #if in c#, what's its use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

How to use this #if statement.
I never used this statement, what is it used for?

[image: Code for #if]

Comment: Conditional compilation

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives

Answer (score 2):

This is a preprocessor directive, used to tell the compiler to only compile if that statement is met.

You can read more here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives